# rails organizing folders for service objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service-object

I'm trying yo create a service object to extract a few methods from the `product.rb` AR model, but for some reason I can't autoload the new `TwitterShare` class. When I hit up the console and try something like `Product.last.twitter_share_text` I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Product::TwitterShare` error.

What's going on in here? How should I organize my folders/files? Do I have to tell rails to autoload services? Here is the current code:

app/models/product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base  

  def twitter_share_text
    TwitterShare.new(name: self.name, oneliner: self.oneliner).return_text
  end
```

app/services/twitter_share.rb

```
class TwitterShare
  attr_reader .........

  def initialize....
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let `rails` know where it could possibly find `TwitterShare`.

Add the following to your `application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/services"
```

and then restart the `console` or `server`.

`rails` should now be able to locate `twitter_share.rb` and load `TwitterShare` correctly.

Refer to [Autoloading and Reloading Constants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Dharam. I wasn't sure if this was the right way. I checked out a github repo where the guy is using the same folder structure but he didn't include this line in the `application.rb`. Thanks to that I thought there must be a better way to do it.